# Raspberry Pi ethernet socket type T-568A or T-568B

Tags: raspberry-pi, ethernet, rj45

I'm using an rpi model B rev 2 as a wifi access point and need to run a long cat6 ethernet cable to its location from the router. It works fine with an off the shelf ethernet cable but I need to make up my own cable for the longer distance to the outside location.

Does it matter on the wiring of the RJ45 on each end of the cable? They obviously need to match at each end but does the rpi need T-568A or T-568B wired RJ45 at its ethernet socket? Or is that not a consideration?

I saw reference to the rpi needing a crossover cable. I presume that means the wiring of the RJ45 at each end should be the "mirror" of each other?

Or is it fine to use a straight through cable of either T-568A or T-568B?

Comment: T-568A or T-568B makes no difference as long as both ends are the same. And any modern router should have auto MDI-X so there is no reason to use a crossover cable anymore.

Comment: thanks for confirming. The hardware spec of the rpi says it supports Auto-MDIX too https://elinux.org/RPi_Hardware#Components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RPi socket is neither because it has no wiring of any colour so it is undefined and not relevant.

And the wire colours don't matter.

The only difference between A and B is which colours are used for which pairs, when connectors are wired together. Either patch cables or infrastructure wiring between sockets.

The wiring of pairs in both T-568 standards is identical except for how the colours are used.